# Getting info from a page that requires Login (Java)

Tags: java, authentication, htmlunit

I'm making a small script that's supposed to get roughly 300 links from a page and make them into shortcuts (all saved in a folder).

I am able to get all the links I need from some pages, but some are part of a website that needs me to log in first.

I tried HttpUnit, but i simply fails every time. Until now I just put the Html page into an inputStream and read from there (line by line, looking for what I need), but I have no clue how to connect to the website or do anything else once I get to the Login part.

Here's the HttpUnit code, if it helps anyone:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

// Get the first page
final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("mywebsite");

ArrayList<HtmlForm> f;
f = (ArrayList<HtmlForm>) page1.getForms();

System.out.println(f);

// Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form, 
// find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
final HtmlForm form = page1.getFirstByXPath("//form[@id='login']");

final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getFirstByXPath("//input[@value='Login']");
final HtmlTextInput username = form.getFirstByXPath("//input[@id='username']");

// Change the value of the text field
username.setValueAttribute("username");

final HtmlPasswordInput passField = form.getFirstByXPath("//input[@id='password']");

// Change the value of the text field
passField.setValueAttribute("pass");

// Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();

webClient.closeAllWindows();
```

please forgive my bad variable naming :p It's a script just for myself, so I didn't really bother.

I get a NullPointerException on "final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your search for the button fails. After this line

```
final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getFirstByXPath("//submit[@value='Login']");
```

I would add

```
assert(button != null) : "Could not find the button";
```

And run your app with assertions on (`-ea` parameter to the JVM) and it will report an assertion failure right there.

Comment: Thanks, I changed that part though, it doesn't give the nullPointerException now, but it still doesn't work.

I get this:

com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Mar 9, 2013 9:27:19 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error

and one CSS Error and a CSS warning.

The Code is right before I'm going to the page that I actally want to get to.

Comment: So you changed the xpath lookup and the button is found correctly now (i.e. button is no longer `null`)?  Where is the new error generated?